# Why does not my compiler show an error when I want to modify a pointer to a constant integer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, local-variables, callstack

This is the code.

```
    int main()
    {int v=2;
    const int *p=&v;
    ++v; //Option 1: Does work, but why should it? 
    // ++*p; //Option 2: Does not work
    }
```

The compiler throws an error for option 2, as expected. But it goes with option 1, when it is modifying the content of a pointer to a constant integer. Why? Or, am I understanding something wrong about the implication of const? Is it applicable only for variables on the heap as opposed to the stack?

Comment: `v` is not const, why shouldn't the compiler allow it to be modified? `const` does not mean "this object cannot ever be modified" - it only means "this object cannot be modified via this pointer or reference".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik A const object cannot ever be modified.  You're talking about non-top-level const-qualifier on a pointer (an important distinction - `const` means different things in different contexts)

Comment: @M.M I was indeed simplifying somewhat - perhaps too much. Though one way to think of a const object is that it cannot be modified because you can never (legally) obtain a non-const pointer or reference to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's legal to cast away const. (But not legal to write a const object through such a pointer)

Answer (score 1):

> Or, am I understanding something wrong about the implication of const?

Yes.

When you have:

```
int v = 2;
const int *p=&v;
```

You are not allowed to modify the object through `p` but you are still allowed to modify the object directly through `v`. You may also modify the object through another pointer.

```
int* p2 = &v
*p2 = 10; // OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` doesn't really mean 'constant', it basically means "read only". When you define a pointer to a const object, it doesn't mean that object can never change--it just means that you can't write to that object *via that pointer*.

In fact, it's perfectly allowable (and sometimes meaningful) to specify that an object is both `const` (so you can't change it) and `volatile` (indicating that something else might change it). For example, back in the MS-DOS days, the BIOS maintained a timer at a an address of `40:6c` (offset 0x6c in segment 0x40), which was updated every ~55 ms, but you shouldn't write it directly, so you could define a pointer to it like:

```
long const volatile *bios_timer = MK_FP(0x40, 0x6c);
```

So, attempting to write to this location (at least via this pointer) was *not* allowed, but the value you'd read from it would change on a regular and ongoing basis.

[Note that contrary to how it may sound above: this (presumably) still exists--but with a protected mode OS, attempting to access it directly in user mode will undoubtedly fail.]